# How to test if there is any significance difference between the areas under under two curves

Tags: statistical-significance, auc

I am trying to test if there is any significant difference between the areas under two curves.

x-axis: length of stay (los)
y-axis: percentage
curve1: control group
curve2: intervene

Any idea how can I do it?

Thanks!